# Contact form give 405 when I send emails using amazon web server

Tags: php, html, forms, amazon-web-services, email

I created an html contact form and added PHP code to help the contact form send emails.

I added my index and PHP file to my amazon web server, but I get this

> error 405 - HTTP verb used to access this page is not allowed. The page you are looking for cannot be displayed because an invalid method (HTTP verb) was used to attempt access.

when I clicked submit button.

Am I missing something basic, is there a configuration that I need to do?

my code below

```
<form action="mail_handler.php" method="post" name="form" class="form-box">
        <label for="name">Name</label><br>
        <input type="text" name="name" class="inp" placeholder="Enter Your Name" required><br>
        <label for="email">Email ID</label><br>
        <input type="email" name="email" class="inp" placeholder="Enter Your Email" required><br>
        <label for="phone">Phone</label><br>
        <input type="tel" name="phone" class="inp" placeholder="Enter Your Phone" required><br>
        <label for="message">Message</label><br>
        <textarea name="msg" class="msg-box" placeholder="Enter Your Message Here..." required></textarea><br>
        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Send" class="sub-btn">
    </form>


<?php
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
    $name=$_POST['name'];
    $email=$_POST['email'];
    $phone=$_POST['phone'];
    $msg=$_POST['msg'];

    $to='myEmailAddress@gmail.com';
    $subject='Form Submission';
    $message="Name :".$name."\n"."Phone :".$phone."\n"."Wrote the following :"."\n\n".$msg;
    $headers="From: ".$email;

    if(mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers)){
        echo "<h1>Sent Successfully! Thank you"." ".$name.", We will contact you shortly!</h1>";
    }
    else{
        echo "Something went wrong!";
    }
  }
?>
```

Comment: `action="mail_handler.php"`
Does that point to the block of code at the bottom? Or is it pointing to a different file?

Comment: Is this script called `mail_handler.php` ??

Comment: yes its pointing to the php code you see there. there are no other codes. this is everything

Comment: i am search about this and i think it's server issue.

Answer (score 0):

The form action points to an external file and not to the code block you're aiming for. :D

```
<form action="mail_handler.php" method="post" name="form" class="form-box">
// action tag refers to a file in current directory, not the php below
```

What this means is that the code is trying to open the file "mail_handler.php" and its not actually there! The error 405 is similar to the classic 404, in that it denotes that there is a missing action.

You will most likely need to move everything in your `<?php` and `?>` tags into a new file.

For more information in checking out PHP form actions, I'd recommend [this article](https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_forms.asp), or perhaps even checking out [Codecademy's PHP Course](https://www.codecademy.com/learn/php) (free)!

> **Edit**
>
> You may have an issue with the following line. `if(mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers))`
>
> The use of the if statement would imply that the return value would always be a Boolean (true/false). However, according the [W3 School's article](https://www.w3schools.com/php/func_mail_mail.asp) on the `mail()` function, it "Returns the hash value of the address parameter, or FALSE on failure."
>
> If this is the cause of your problem, you would probably want to do something like the following.

```
if(!mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers)){
    echo "Something went wrong!"; 
    // You know the only time its gone wrong is when it returns false.
}
else{
    echo "<h1>Success message!</h1>
    // If it returns anything other than false, then its a success
}
```

Comment: the php code is in a separate file called mail_handler.php

Comment: thanks so much! i will try this out and let you know if it works

Comment: nah i changed it, and i still get the error 405 - HTTP verb used to access this page is not allowed.
The page you are looking for cannot be displayed because an invalid method (HTTP verb) was used to attempt access.

Comment: Do you know of any decent examples online, contact form that works

Comment: Try this one! http://www.freecontactform.com/email_form.php Have you checked to make sure your service is normal and there are abnormalities being experienced?